# Refused to execute script Reserved.ReportViewerControl.axd in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, asp.net, reporting-services

We are migrating our ASP.NET WebForms and MVC 3.5 Application to our new SharePoint 2013.

Lots of our applications use Reporting Services which use ReportViewer Control 9.0 but when we deployed the application inside SharePoint, the below error always appears in IE and the Chrome Console Log :

[image]

ON IE 11 : Server Browser

```
SEC7112: Script from 
http://OurSite.com/Reports/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=9.0.30729.1&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Scripts.ReportViewer.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

Anyone experience the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally i solve my problem.

I just removed the **“X-Content-Type-Options"** with value **"nosniff"** on my SharePoint site HTTP Header and restart IIS.

Hope this help other folks experiencing the same issue :D

Comment: I have faced similar issue recently and found the discrepancy in mime type for report viewer in version 8, version 10 (maybe even 9) is having this fixed and there is no need to remove security header.